# Выбор необходимой коллекции

Tags: коллекции, java

Добрый день. Возникла задача, в которой есть два поля: Имя Сотрудника , Зарплата. (Нужно использовать коллекции). Нужно отсортировать сотрудников по уменьшению зарплаты , и если попадутся сотрудники с одинаковой зарплатой, то нужно отсортировать сотрудников по их имени а алфавитном порядке. С начала хотел применить TreeMap, но мне нужно будет отсортировать не только ключи но и значения. Подскажите пожалуйста, какую структуру данных можно использовать ?

Answer (score 5):

во первых

причём тут коллекции? вам нужно реализовать `Interface Comparable<T>` в котором выполнять необходимые сравнения, или создать свой Comparator.

во вторых

Коллекции отличаются тем как хранятся данные. За счёт хранения вы можете выиграть в скорости работы с данными или с объёмом памяти, но беда в том что нужно знать какая работа будет проводиться над данными.

Comment: Из операций только сортировка списка (помимо удаления или добавления элементов в список). Сортировать нужно как ключи так и значения

Comment: вы несёте глупость!  

как я понял у вас есть класс в котором два поля {имя,зарплата} вы что в коллекцию их порознь запихиваете?


вам нужно для вашего класса в котором два поля {имя,зарплата} реализовать интерфейс `Interface Comparable<T>` в котором проводить сравнение и выдавать результат, после этого вы сможете использовать любую удобную коллекцию и вызывать стандартную сортировку...

Comment: и ещё советую использовать обычный список или массив, по крайней мере до тех пор пока вы не будете понимать разницу между разными структурами данных. Вам как минимум нужно освоить структуры данных array, list, stack, AVL-tree, RB-tree, hash-tree и "BIG O" нотацию

Comment: мне нужно использовать коллекции, т.к. мне нужно работать с id работника, а это как я понимаю можно реализовать в коллекциях

Comment: ещё больше убедился что у вас каша в голове! срочно наводите порядок! разберитесь в структурах данных и коллекциях их реализующих.

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class uDataSort {

    public static void main(String a[]){

        TreeSet<Empl> employee = new TreeSet<Empl>(new SalaryComp());

        employee.add(new Empl("Ram",3000));
        employee.add(new Empl("John",6000));
        employee.add(new Empl("Crish",2000));
        employee.add(new Empl("Tom",1400));
        employee.add(new Empl("Alfred",2000));
        employee.add(new Empl("Tomas",2000));
        employee.add(new Empl("Adolf",2000));

        for(Empl e:employee){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

}

class SalaryComp implements Comparator<Empl>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Empl e1, Empl e2) {
        if(e1.getSalary() < e2.getSalary()){
            return 1;
        } else if (e1.getSalary() == e2.getSalary()) {
            return e1.getName().compareTo(e2.getName());
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }

        }
    }

class Empl{

    private String name;
    private int salary;

    public Empl(String n, int s){
        this.name = n;
        this.salary = s;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "Name: "+this.name+"-- Salary: "+this.salary;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) подойдет. Но [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) все равно нужно реализовать свой.
Подойдет также любой список, который нужно будет отсортировать использовав все тот же компаратор.

Comment: Но ведь List не содержит ключа. Мне казалось, что только Map подойдет.

Comment: @Drylozav ТЗ не содержало требований о ключах :)

Comment: +1 за TreeSet, т.к. значения в нем  уже будут отсортированы от меньшего к большему(если числа), либо в алфавитном порядке.
Но как неоднократно писалось раньше, **Comparator** нужен свой